# Firebase Cloud Messaging isn't reporting any metrics(received, open rates) while used in PWA Nextjs client

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using `firebase-messaging-sw.js` as a service worker to listen for any push notifcations. Even `firebase-analytics` is enabled.

`firebase-messaging-sw.js`

```
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-app.js");
importScripts(
  "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-messaging.js"
);

const firebaseConfig = {...
};

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = firebaseApp.messaging();

messaging.onBackgroundMessage((payload) => {
  console.log(
    "[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ",
    payload
  );
  // Customize notification here
  const notificationTitle = "Background Message Title";
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: "Background Message body.",
    icon: "/firebase-logo.png",
  };

  self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
});
```

Using "notificationonclick" event to handle opening push notification.

Also, using `next-pwa` for Nextjs based PWA.

Open rates, received FCM metrics aren't updating at all. Also, there's no documentation stating anything regarding it as it's auto-configured with FCM and firebase analytics.